# How can I kill a process from a Java application, if I know the PID of this process? I am looking for a cross-platfrom solution

Tags: java, process, cross-platform

I know there are several ways to kill a process from Java, but all of these use some kind of platform-specific code that only works on Windows or Linux.

Is there a lib I can use where I can just call something like

```
Process.kill(pid);
```

Or perhaps there is a method that I can write that handles (almost) all cases of OS?

All I want to do is terminate a process, knowing it's PID already.

Comment: To be cross-platform, you would have to create the `Process` (hint: that's a class name) yourself and then call its termination method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Java 9 there's [`ProcessHandle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html) which allows interaction with all processes on a system (constrained by system permissions of course).

Specifically [`ProcessHandle.of(knownPid)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#of(long)) will return the `ProcessHandle` for a given PID (technically an `Optional` which may be empty if no process was found) and [`destroy`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#destroy()) or [`destroyForcibly`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html#destroyForcibly()) will attempt to kill the process.

I.e.

```
long pid = getThePidViaSomeWay();
Optional<ProcessHandle> maybePh = ProcessHandle.of(pid);
ProcessHandle ph = maybePh.orElseThrow(); // replace with  your preferred way to handle no process being found.
ph.destroy(); //or
ph.destroyForcibly(); // if you want to be more "forcible" about it
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Is there perhaps a Java 1.8 alternative?

Comment: No. Java 8 only had `Process` which serves a similar function but only works with processes started by the JVM itself (i.e. doesn't allow interaction with arbitrary processes). Please consider that Java 8 was released 8 years ago and has not received any public/free updates by Oracle for almost 2 years now. You should **really** switch to a more recent release.

Comment: Thanks. Strangely, I tried your code with Java 1.8 (forcing Maven to compile for a 1.8 target) and I get no errors.

Comment: @user5123481566: you probably just switched the language level to Java 8 but still built with a later JDK without specifying a bootstrap classpath. That's an easy way to get classes that will just crash at runtime when actually run on Java 8.

Comment: OK thanks I will update my target version.